# materialui selectField does not work properly with Redux forms

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am using materialUi with redux form i have following code

NumbersSelector.js

```
import React from 'react';

import SelectField from 'material-ui/SelectField';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

class NumbersSelector extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      value: 1
    }
  }

  _renderItems = input => {

    let items = [];

    for (let i = this.props.minValue; i <= this.props.maxValue; i++ ) {
        i!==1
          ?items.push (<MenuItem {...input} key={i} value={i} primaryText={i + ' ' + this.props.pluralText}/>)
          :items.push (<MenuItem {...input} key={i} value={i} primaryText={i + ' ' + this.props.singularText}/>);
    }

    return items;

  }

  render () {

    const { input } = this.props;
    return (
      <SelectField
        name={this.props.name}
        maxSearchResults={this.props.maxSearchResults}
        floatingLabelText={this.props.floatingLabelText}
        hintText={this.props.hintText}

        fullWidth={true}
        floatingLabelFixed={true}

        inputStyle={this.props.inputStyle}
        floatingLabelStyle={this.props.floatingLabelStyle}
        hintStyle={this.props.hintStyle}

        value={input.value}
        onChange={(event, value) => {console.log(value);input.onChange(value)}}
      >
        {this._renderItems(input)}
      </SelectField>
    );
  }

}

export default NumbersSelector;
```

I use above component as follows

```
<Field
          component={NumbersSelector}
          name={'noOfNights'}
          floatingLabelText="No of Nights"
          hintText="Click to select"
          hintStyle={searchPanelHintStyles}
          inputStyle={searchPanelInputStyles}
          floatingLabelStyle={searchPanelFloatingLabelFixedStyles}
          floatingLabelFixed={true}
          fullWidth={true}
          minValue={1}
          maxValue={10}
          singularText="Night"
          pluralText="Nights"
       />
```

This creates a list with numbers. The issue is when i select one from the menu items, Instead of the clicked one it selects the above item from the clicked item.

For example if the number 7 is clicked then number 6 get selected

How do i fix this ***without using redux-form-material-ui***.

[DEMO](http://www.webpackbin.com/EJZEl3nQM)

Comment: May be you could reproduce it here? I set it up, but the select doen't work at all. http://www.webpackbin.com/VkFLH_3Xf Post link after you save it.

Comment: Hey @Anarion i could not find what the error is there. Thanks for your effort really appreciates

Comment: May be start from scratch. Being able to work with working code will help to solve the problem. Does everything work if you try to use regular Select control insted of material-ui?

Comment: @Anarion you were missing react-tap-event-plugin :) Please visit http://www.webpackbin.com/EJZEl3nQM

Comment: when this plugin is included the site stops working :D I can't switch between file tabs.  They must be using the same thing and it breaks their site

Comment: @Anarion Are you using the latest version of react (15.4.0) and react-tap-event-plugin (2.0.1)

Comment: I was trying to use the link to the fiddle that you provided. didn't set it up locally - but seems like that's what I will have to do, because fiddle turns crazy with this plugin included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguments passed to `onChange` for `SelectField` are `(event, index, value)` , so you were using `index` instead of `value`.

change your `onChange={(event, value)` to `onChange={(event, index, value)`

docs at [MaterialUI SelectField](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field)